# Gratis PPPoe server for testing porpoises

Tags: windows, gratis, android, pppoe

I am developing an app which has to communicate over PPPoE.

I am looking for a gratis PPPoE server with which my client can communicate.

Windows or Android, please. MUST be free for commercial use. If Windows, it should be portable as I don't have admin rights at work.

Nice to have would be some sort of debugging, where, for instance, it shows the commands which it receives.